# appending last node in drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am using the following code:

```
function deleteImage2($item)
{
    $item.fadeOut(function()
    {
        var $list = $('ul',$albumcover).length ? $('ul',$albumcover) : $('<ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset"/>').appendTo($albumcover);
        $item.appendTo($list).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

"albumcover" is name of DIV and this code is working fine, but I need to append last node, how can I modify this query?

Kind Regards

Comment: Please provide your html code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function deleteImage2($item)
{
    $item.fadeOut(function()
    {
        var $list = ($('ul',$albumcover).length ? $('ul:last',$albumcover) : $('<ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset"/>')).appendTo($albumcover);
        $item.appendTo($list).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

add `:last` in your selector to select only last item